# Postgres statement pipes enclosing quoted colons

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, pipe, psql

What does it mean when a SQL statement in postgres is written like the following?

```
SELECT 
    name||' ::: '||id AS title
FROM 
    my_table;
```

It's almost impossible to search in Google! What do the pipes and enclosed quoted colons do?

Comment: `||` concatenates two string values in SQL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL):

> **Function:** `string || string`
>   **Return Type**: `text`
>   **Description**: `String concatenation`
>   **Example**: `'Post' || 'greSQL'`
>   **Result**: `PostgreSQL`

So `a || b` is string concatenation. This is standard SQL, some non-standard databases use `concat(a, b)` or `a + b`.

Single quotes are used in (standard) SQL for string literals so `' ::: '` is just a string.

That means that the whole thing:

```
name||' ::: '||id
```

is just the `name` and `id` pasted together with `' ::: '` between them. That SQL would probably be easier to read if the author added a little bit of whitespace:

```
name || ' ::: ' || id
```

BTW, you'll have better luck using [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com) to search for such things:

> http://symbolhound.com/?q=postgresql+%7C%7C

Comment: +1 for SymbolHound. Does the job for the case at hand: http://symbolhound.com/?q=postgres+||

Answer (score 0):

This simply do a select statement for two fields of the table by concatenating them with a text ' ::: ' at the middle.